# How to find the residue of$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-e^{2z})}$ at simple poles $z=ni\pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How to find the residue of

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-e^{2z})}$$

at simple poles $z=n\pi i $?

I know how to find the residue of a function on a simple pole with  a formula about that, but here I can't use that...
I also know that the result should be $\frac{i}{2n\pi}$ , but I don't know how can I get this...
Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: $e^{2z}=1$ --> $z=n\pi i$ ...?

Comment: You're completely right, of course.

Comment: *but here I can't use that...* - why?!

Comment: @metamorphy formula goes: $ lim(z->in\pi)   (z-in\pi)*f(z)$ , and I don't think I get something that can help me....

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you!

Comment: Look at the second formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles).

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks a lot! I didn't know about that formula:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The residues at $z = in\pi$, $n \in \Bbb{Z} \text{\\} \{0\}$ can be calculated directly

$$\lim_{z\to in\pi} \frac{z-in\pi}{z(1-e^{2z})} \equiv -\frac{1}{in\pi}\cdot \frac{1}{(e^{2z})'}\Biggr|_{z=in\pi} = \frac{i}{2n\pi}$$

The residue at $z = 0$ can be calculated by Taylor expanding the denominator

$$\frac{1}{z(1-e^{2z})} = \frac{1}{z(-2z-2z^2-\cdots)} = -\frac{1}{2z^2(1+z+\cdots)} = -\frac{1}{2z^2}(1-z+\cdots)$$

$$ = -\frac{1}{2z^2} + \frac{1}{2z} - \cdots$$

which gives a residue of $\frac{1}{2}$